# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ';', expecting ')' in *:\Users\******\******\xampp\htdocs\******\inc\php\arrays.php on line 25

Tags: php

```
<?php
if(!defined('AccessPermitted')){
    die('Direct access not permitted!');
}

$users = array(
    'root' => '$2y$10$S4I6KYGRJchekcNvFOVOhOsQTP9wPafrKAbh95VxAhyC6iJ6GzwUq',
    'ceo' => '$2y$10$EO84saam8Y7bir7wVLwrJOA5Pp5tBJKQyfq0vr10jsNWS5FpgfRvO',
    'test123' => '$2y$10$OrspF.C5MwQShdVjhgmsSOi67k3/OF/05wbQa4fHZEa8vtoFzwnty'
);

$admins = array(
    'root'
);

$staff = array(
    'ceo'
);

$tools = array(
    'xtr3m3' => array(
        'root',
        'ceo',
        'test123'
    );
);
```

I'm having trouble with the above-standing code.
It says it's an error, but I think it's just bullshitting...
I really don't know how to fix this...
Thanks in advance!
And yes, I want the login to use an array, I don't want any DataBases.

Comment: [*"An array can be created using the array() language construct. It takes any number of **comma-separated** key => value pairs as arguments."*](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php)

Comment: $tools = array(
    'xtr3m3' => array(
        'root',
        'ceo',
        'test123'
    ); <!-- Remove this semicolon; -->
);

Comment: "I think the computer is bullshitting" the computer usually doesnt make mistakes. like 99% of them are the user.

Answer (score 0):

Before last line you have `;` character which is invalid.

```
$tools = array(
    'xtr3m3' => array(
        'root',
        'ceo',
        'test123'
    );
);
```

should be

```
$tools = array(
    'xtr3m3' => array(
        'root',
        'ceo',
        'test123'
    )
);
```

Comment: Hmm, thanks, but now it says, 'Direct Access not Permitted', but I defined 'DirectAccess'

Comment: I don't see where it is call to `define('AccessPermitted')` in your code. Basically, your error was fixed, you can mark asnwer as correct. Your next problem is based on your structure of program.

Comment: It's in the login.php, which contains this:
`define('AccessPermitted', TRUE);
include('./inc/php/arrays.php');`